# How to make this content div 100% of available height?

Tags: css, html

```
//// html ////
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="menu"> menu </div>
        <div class="content"> {% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div class="footer"> footer </div> 
    </div>
</body>


//// css ////
```

```css
html, body {
background: black;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;

}

.page {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.menu {
background: #ff0000;
height: 100px;
}

.content {
padding-bottom: 75px;
background: #00ff00;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
height: 75px;
background: #0000ff;
}
```

Output:

[image]

I'll give you a link to jsFiddle but it isn't working properly (not the same as in my browser) - http://jsfiddle.net/t3Gjx/3/ 
I need to get rid of black gaps, no matter how long is the content in green field (content field). I was trying with

```
min-height = 100%
```

in .content but with no success.

Comment: Do you want the header and footer to have a fixed position, or should content stretch out?

Comment: If you're trying to get the green background to cover the entire content, it's easier to just set the background color of the body and leave the content with a transparent background. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3CCDD/

Comment: @LinkinTED header and footer is already at fixed position, so I need to stretch out content.

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo colors are just for example to show where is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/t3Gjx/10/

```
html, body {
    background: black;
    height: 100%;

}

.page {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -75px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

.menu {
    background: #ff0000;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 555;
}

.content {
    background: #00ff00;
    margin: -100px 0 -75px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%; 
}

.content:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

**Explanation:**

This uses the techniques outlined by this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

You make the .page 100% in height, and a set a negative margin at the bottom for the footer to collapse into.  This ensures that the site isn't 100% in height + the height of the footer.  The content uses a before and after block, plus negative margins to make itself 100% in height, minus the menu and footer.

Comment: Thanks! With `margin: 0;` in `html, body {...}` it's working exactly as planned :)

Comment: @Axel, are there any browsers that my struggle with your 100% body height solution, that you may know of?  Thanks for the work.

Comment: @Axel , is it hard to add another div like in this example (black field) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Gjx/13/) (I've just changed `width:` in `.content` to 80% to show where is a problem). I was trying by adding `clear: both;` to `.footer` and `float:left` to `.content` and `float:right` to `right-div` but this solution isn't working

Comment: What are the results you are trying to achieve (overall)?  Are you trying to extend a background image or color to the height of `.content` and a sidebar?

Comment: @Axel I drew that layout to make it clear -> [layout](http://i.imgur.com/y08ND7Y.png)

Comment: I understand.  I'm asking more specifically why you want the content and sidebar to extend to 100% in height, instead of just increasing the height as the content as it fills them (default behavior).

Comment: @Axel because I want footer always at the bottom but if it is possible to do that in another way it'll be great too ;) And I wrote "height depends on amount of content" so it can be 50%, 70%, etc, not always 100% as you mention

Comment: Ah, the way you described it made it seemed like it was important for the content container to be 100% height.  What you're asking for is a bit more simple.  For the 2 column layout, are you looking for fixed width, or a responsive (variable) width layout?

Comment: @Axel It would be great if left column (content container) will be responsive width and right column (sidepanel) - fixed width. If it's not possible or too complicated, let it be responsive for both columns :)
EDIT
Yes, this is responsive for 2 columns, but it is great too! Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT3*** I apologize for all the edits. Final edit on @Axel's jsfiddle.  This works the best i think:
http://codepen.io/k/pen/qJwez.

I added 
`position:relative; z-index: 999;` to the footer and

`z-index: 998;` to the content and

`margin:0` to html,body.

and moved the footer into the page element in the html.

---

Concerning @Axel 's answer: If you have a lot of content it will overflow past the footer.  I added this to his http://jsfiddle.net/t3Gjx/10/  :

`position:relative; z-index: 999;` to the footer and

`z-index: 998;` to the content and

'overflow: auto' to the page.

to prevent this from happening.  The footer still stays at the bottom and the menu and content scroll.

**EDIT**: added modification to the page element

**EDIT2**: also,  after the above modifications, if you move the footer element into the page element in the html, everything should scroll, including the footer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Menu/Content/Status</title>
    <style>
    #menu-bar {
        display         : block;
        position        : absolute;
        left            : 0;
        top             : 0;
        right           : 0;
        height          : 30px;
        margin          : 2px;
        padding         : 2px;
        border          : 1px solid darkgray;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    #status-bar {
        display         : block;
        position        : absolute;
        left            : 0;
        bottom          : 0;
        right           : 0;
        height          : 30px;
        margin          : 2px;
        padding         : 2px;
        border          : 1px solid darkgray;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    #content {
        display         : block;
        position        : absolute;
        left            : 0;
        top             : 38px;
        bottom          : 38px;
        right           : 0;
        margin          : 2px;
        padding         : 2px;
        border          : 1px solid darkgray;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu-bar"  >Menu bar</div>
    <div id="status-bar">Status bar</div>
    <div id="content"   >Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```